# Angular Two way databinding and http.post issue

Tags: angularjs, http, post

Objective: Two Way Databinding between database and view via scope and controller

I’m trying to post to a restful database using angular

When I click on the thumbs up or thumbs down  the scope changes o.k and is reflected in the view

However how can this placed in real time to a restful database using http post  ?

Here’s the HTML

```
     <div ng-controller="ordersCtrl">

     <div class="span0 well votingWidget">
                <div class="votingButton" ng-click="upVoteOrder(order)">
                    <i class="icon-thumbs-up "></i>
                </div>
                <div class="badge ">
                    <div>{{order.upVoteCount}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="votingButton" ng-click="downVoteOrder(order)">
                    <i class="icon-thumbs-down"></i>
                </div>




          Heres the Controller: My issue lies here in the http.post command 


  .controller("ordersCtrl", function ($scope, $http, ordersUrl) {

   $scope.downVoteOrder = function(order) {
       $scope.selectedOrder = order;
        order.upVoteCount--;
         $http.post(orderUrl,  order.upVoteCount)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.data.orderupVoteCount = data.id;

        })
};
```

});

Note : I can post form data to the restful database  successfully  using the following  code

```
     $scope.sendOrder = function (shippingDetails) {
        var order = angular.copy(shippingDetails);
        order.products = cart.getProducts();
        $http.post(orderUrl, order)
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.data.orderId = data.id;
                cart.getProducts().length = 0;
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.data.orderError = error;
            }).finally(function () {
                $location.path("/uploaded");
            });
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Also, shouldn't you send a JSON in the post instead of only the `order.upVoteCount`?

Answer (score 0):

you should use a separate service to handle the http post .

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

    app.factory("OrderService", ["$http", function ($http) {

    this.PostDownVote =  function(orderUrl, upVoteCount) {
            return $http.post(orderUrl, upVoteCount);   
    }    

    this.PostOrder = function(orderUrl, order) {
     // do something
    }

    return this;
}]);
```

Now inject this OrderService to you controller and use it.

```
app.controller("ordersCtrl", function ($scope, $http, ordersUrl, OrderService) {

    $scope.downVoteOrder = function(order) {
        $scope.selectedOrder = order;
        order.upVoteCount--;
        OrderService.PostDownVote(ordersUrl, order.upVoteCount)
                     .success(data) {// do            something}
                      .error(data) {// do something}

    }
});
```